# Node.js PGAdmin Google Cloud Connecttion

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

In [ProjectA] I have

1. A VM Instance running Node.js
2. A cloud PGAdmin Database.

I need help to connect the database from the Node Application. I am getting this error.

```
Error: connect ENOENT /[InstanceName]/.s.PGSQL.5432 at PipeConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1106:14)
errno: 'ENOENT',  code: 'ENOENT', syscall: 'connect', address: ‘/[InstanceName]/.s.PGSQL.5432'
```

Suggestions/help would really be appreciated. This is my connection in the node.

```
user: 'postgres',//host: ‘[Host-Name]',
socketPath: ['Host-name', //host:[ExternalIP],
database: [Database],
password: [Password],
```

Answer (score 0):

As the database is in Cloud SQL in the same project what you can do to connect is to use the Cloud SQL Proxy and by that you will be able to connect as to a local database to your VM.

To install and run the cloud SQL proxy you can follow [This](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/sql-proxy), I also put the instructions in general here:

1) Get the SQL Proxy and make it executable. For this you need to run the following 2 line in the VM:

```
wget https://dl.google.com/cloudsql/cloud_sql_proxy.linux.amd64 -O cloud_sql_proxy

chmod +x cloud_sql_proxy
```

2) Create a service Account with the role of CloudSQL Client as detailed [here](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts)

3) Create a key for the service account and upload it to your VM

4) Start the SQL proxy by running this command:

```
./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>=tcp:5432 \
                  -credential_file=<PATH_TO_KEY_FILE> &
```

5) Connect in your app as if the Database was in localhost